# How to delete those 1D lists within a 2D list which contains with duplicate 1st element?

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-2.7

Say I have a 2D list(of floats only)-

`a=[[1,2],[1,3],[2,5],[4,3],[3,4],[4,9]]`
and I want to remove those 1D lists which have the common 1st element and occur later. For example- the first list [1,2] contains 1 as the first element, so delete the next list with 1st element 1, which in this case is the 2nd list [1,3], then we take [2,5],[4,3],[3,4] as usual but since we took [4,3] already we won't take the [4,9] which has the common first element 4.

So the final output should be-

`[[1,2],[2,5],[4,3],[3,4]]`

How can this be done in Python? I can think of some nested for loops and a bunch of if else statements which would be clearly inefficient and I hope there is a trick with set/map/zip functions which is a bit more Pythonic.

Comment: You should try to write some code and show it. It's fine if it's inefficient, but you should show *something*. A simple iteration and and `seen=set()` should actually work fine.

Comment: I would have done that after reading your comment but you people are so fast at replying! :-)
Anyway my code was on the lines of the answer by user KnowledgeGainer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `set()` to filter out the duplicates:

```py
a = [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 5], [4, 3], [3, 4], [4, 9]]

out, seen = [], set()
for item in a:
    if not item[0] in seen:
        seen.add(item[0])
        out.append(item)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[[1, 2], [2, 5], [4, 3], [3, 4]]
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[[1,2],[1,3],[2,5],[4,3],[3,4],[4,9]]
k=[]
[a.remove(i) if i[0] in k else k.append(i[0]) for i in a]
print(a)
```

Comment: This should work, but it's confusing code, because you're creating a list, with list comprehension syntax, that you don't care about, and just throw away. It's best to use a regular for loop if you're just going to throw away the list created by the comprehension.

Comment: I agree with you,It can be done with regular for loop, although I was trying to decrease the lines of code.